# pass variable to extract data from mongodb meteor

Tags: meteor

My mongodb looks like this : [image]

I want to access the names of array in doubtThread followed.

Following is my code :

Template.showDoubts.onCreated(function(){

```
this.uid = null;
this.uid = UserDetails.findOne({userId : Meteor.userId()});
this.count = 0;
this.cname = this.uid.channelsSubscribed[Session.get('doubtIndex')]
```

});

```
IsnoDoubtsFollowed : function(){
    var flag = false;
    _.each(_.keys(Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed), function(key){
        console.log('key : ' + key);
        if(key == Template.instance().cname){
            console.log('values : ' + Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.key);
            flag = true;
        }
    });
```

Basically I want to retrieve  Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.key where key is the variable name. Is it not possible to pass the key of object as a variable?

Apologies if the language isn't clear.

Comment: I also tried passing Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.Session.get('cname')   and   Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.Template.instance().cname  but error persisits. For the first scenario, it says cannot read property 'get' of undefined.   For the second scenario, it says cannot read property instance of undefined

Comment: i know i can retrieve the key value by using _.keys function of underscorejs. My question is that how to pass that value to Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.key (because this shows undefined. key is a variable here and not a static field)

Comment: Please include the code where you set the uid property in the template instance.

Comment: Also, are you getting any exceptions? If so, please include those as well.

Comment: added the code for uid. and no, i got no exceptions. console.log(Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.key) is undefined but i want the array values there. problem key here. It works fine if i print Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed.algebra   (algebra is one of the keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what the primary purpose of this code is, but to get an object's property by using a variable's value as a key, use brackets. e.g. `someObject[variable]`. Then your code could look like:

```
IsnoDoubtsFollowed : function(){
    let flag = false;
    const doubtThreadFollowed = Template.instance().uid.doubtThreadFollowed;
    Object.keys(doubtThreadFollowed).forEach(function(key) {
        console.log('key : ' + key);
        if(key === Template.instance().cname) {
            console.log('values: ', doubtThreadFollowed[key]);
            flag = true;
        }
    });
});
```